# Interpolating Function inside of NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, interpolation

I have a problem and it seems to be connected to an Interpolating function inside of an `NDSolv`e command. The `resistivity[x`] function inside the `NDSolve` command is an interpolation of measurement data. The code works fine with an ordinary function instead of the interpolating function. When I run the code, it does not give an error, but no results are displayed either. Does anybody know what the problem is?

The code is:

```
xydataplot = Reap[
     For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
       J = i j;
       s = 
       NDSolve[{y'[x] == (resistivity[y[x]]  J^2)/nC 
        - alpha/nC (-T + y[x]), y[0] == T}, y, {x, 0, t}];
       Te = y[t] /. s;
       resis2 = resistivity[Te];
       efeld = J resis2;
       Sow[efeld];
       Sow[J];
       ];
     ][[2, 1]]~Partition~2;
```

Comment: Can you please fix the code you have used in your question? It should be a minimal example which works and shows the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code, one can only guess:

Try to redefine your `resistivity` functions as

```
resistivity[in_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[ListInterpolation[yourData]];
```

and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The problem was apparently, that the Te output was a list with one entry instead of a single value. Just evaluating First[Te] made the code work. But thank you very much for your idea!